# Picard group of double cover branched along reducible divisor

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be the double cover of $\mathbb{P}^2$ branched along a divisor which is union of two lines. Then what will be the $\text{Pic}(X)$ ? Is it torsion free ? If yes, then what is its generator ?

Answer (score 4):

This double cover is a quadratic cone in $\mathbb{P}^3$, its Picard group is $\mathbb{Z}$, it is generated by the hyperplane class, equivalently by the pullback of a line class from $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: Suppose it is branched along $l_1 \cup l_2$ and let $C_1, C_2$ are the inverse image of $l_1, l_2$ respectively.  Then  how to write $\mathcal{O}_X(C_1)$ in terms of pullback of the hyperplane class ?

Comment: What do you precisely mean by the inverse images of $l_i$? If the pullbacks, then these are just hyperplane classes.

Comment: By the inverse image i mean $\pi^{-1} (l_i)$ where $\pi : X \to \mathbb{P}^2$ is the covering map. I did not mean the pullback.

Comment: Being the inverse image of a closed subset $l_i$, $C_i$ is a closed subset (hence a divisor in $X$)

Comment: As @Sasha explained, $X$ is a quadratic cone. Your $C_i$'s are just 2 generatrices of this cone. They are Weil divisors, not Cartier.

Comment: If you take $\pi^{-1}(l_i)$ as a scheme then it gives you the hyperplane class; if you take it as a set, this is a Weil divisor (not Carier) whose double is the hyperplane class.

Comment: If we resolve the singularity of $X$, i.e., if we consider the blow up of $X$ at the intersection points $C_1 \cap C_2$, and consider the proper transform of $C_i$, then it would be a Cartier divisor. I guess this proper transform will be linearly equivalent to the exceptional divisor. Am I correct ?

Comment: No — the exceptional divisor does not move linearly. Your blown up surface fibers onto $\Bbb{P}^1$, the proper transforms are fibers, while the exceptional divisor is horizontal.

Comment: How we write down the line bundle associated to the divisor $\tilde{C_1}$ in terms of the generators which are the pullback of hyperplane bundle and associated to the exceptional  divisor, where $\tilde{C_i}$ is the proper transform of $C_i$ ?

Comment: Is it the pullback of hyperplane bundle tensored with $\mathcal{O}_{\tilde{X}}(-E)$ ?